# How to get a List from Flux without blocking?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a repository that returns a flux and wanted to set the result to another object which is expecting a list. Is there any other way to get the results as a list without blocking?

The block is working but it is taking long time.

```
public class FluxToListTest {

    @Autowired PostRepository postRepository;

    public void setUserPosts(User user) {
      user.setPostList(postRepository.findAllByOrderId(user.getId()).collectList().block());
  }
}


interface PostRepository {

    Flux<Post> findAllByOrderId(final UUID userId);
}


@Data
class User {
  UUID id;
  List<Post> postList;
}


class Post {
    UUID id;
    String content;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In short  - **NO**.
You don't need to extract `List` from `Flux`.
If you've started use Reactor Streams - stay with it.

Try this code:

```
public void setUserPosts(User user) {
    postRepository.findAllByOrderId(user.getId())
        .collectList()
        .doOnNext(user::setPostList)// (1)
        .subscribe();               // (2) 
}
```

1. if you set operation is blocking please use [publishOn](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publishOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-)/[subscribeOn](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#subscribeOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-) to avoid blocking for the all stream.
2. it starts your stream performing

Comment: Keep in mind that this could be misleading to the caller of your method. If someone calls `setUserPosts(User user)` it will return immediately so a `getUserPosts(User user)` call may not be able to read what it just "wrote".